# Angular 2 Media Queries

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I want to know that does Angular 2 provides a way to determine the client's device (large screen, medium or smalls screen) or may be screen width on the basic of which some contents could be shown or hidden (removed from dom).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HostListener**

One way is to use the [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator. The decorated method will be invoked when the host element emits the specified event.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.width = event.target.innerWidth;
  this.height = event.target.innerHeight;
}
```

**Via ngZone**

Another way is to import [ngZone](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html) into your component. Then you can use `NgZone` to check the `onresize` event.

```typescript
constructor(ngZone:NgZone) {
  window.onresize = (e) => {
    ngZone.run(() => {
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
    });
  };
}
```

After that you can use the `[hidden]` attribute to hide content depends from your *width* or *height* value.

Comment: Thank you so much Maximilian. One more question, does using NgZone adds any overhead or may cause any performance issue?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed My understanding is that NgZone#run can be used in the handler for some asynchronous process that runs outside of Angular change detection.  In this case, we want to react to `onresize` events which are emitted from outside of Angular, so in order to react to that event within angular's change detection cycles, we can register a listener for that event on the window and use `run` to schedule handling to be executed from within the angular zone.  TLDR while you could have performance issues if you schedule too much logic to be executed in the zone, this example looks ok to me.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to use NgZone. There are easier ways to capture the resize window event.

```typescript
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  this.width = target.innerWidth;
  this.height = target.innerHeight;
}
```

or if you want to use if from the HTML

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)"

onResize(event) {
  event.target.innerWidth;
}
```